# jQuery.validate.js onkeyup = true error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

With my jquery validation configuration, I get the following error when setting onkeyup to true. It works if I set it to false, but I don't get validation feedback until I blur the field, and I'm looking to get validation on each keyup:

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
        onkeyup: true,        
        onclick: false
        // rules omitted for brevity
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: validator.settings[eventType].call is not a function
validator.settings[eventType].call(validator, this[0], event);
jquery.validate.js line 391
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You actually need to set the `onkeyup` option to a function that accepts the element being validated as a parameter, so try changing:

```
onkeyup: true,
```

to

```
onkeyup: function(element) {$(element).valid()}
```

Comment: Simply removing the `onkeyup` option restores the "onkeyup" functionality already built into the plugin, which is somewhat more complex than `$(element).valid()`.

Comment: @AdamLevitt, removing `onkeyup` entirely restores its default functionality, which is "on key-up".  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZvvTa/

Comment: Sparky, what's the difference between onkeyup and keyup? The default functionality for some reason isn't working for me.  If I remove onkeyup completely, it doesn't work as desired.  But with the solution in this answer, it does work. I'd prefer your solution if I could get it to work.

Comment: @AdamLevitt, `onkeyup` is an valid option for this plugin. `keyup` is nothing... it's a made-up word as far as this plugin is concerned.  For the proper way to get **immediate** "on key-up" validation, see the edits on my answer.

Answer (score 37):

`onkeyup` is enabled by default so you do not need to set it to `true`.  If you do, you break the functionality already built into the plugin.

**You have three options:**

---

**1)**  Leave the `onkeyup` option out of `.validate()`.  This keeps `onkeyup` functionality **enabled** by default.  (edit:  "by default" means that validation occurs on every "key-up" event *only after* the field is initially validated by another event.)

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZvvTa/

---

**2)**  `onkeyup` can be set to `false` to **disable** this option.

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZvvTa/1/

---

**3)**  Replace `onkeyup` with your own callback function to **modify** how it operates. (Demo uses default function)

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZvvTa/2/

Below is the **default**, **unmodified**, `onkeyup` callback function:

```
onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
    if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" ) {
        return;
    } else if ( element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastElement ) {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

---

See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

---

**EDIT**:

By default, the plugin does not do any "key-up" validation until *after* the field is initially validated by another event.  *("Lazy" validation)*

So here is a more properly modified version of the `onkeyup` callback function that will provide *immediate* `onkeyup` validation.  *("Eager" validation)*

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/QfKk7/**

```
onkeyup: function (element, event) {
    if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
        return;
    } else {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sparky, thanks so much for your dedicated efforts.  Would recommend that I just manually put this function into the instance of the onkeyup? Or is it safe to replace the default implementation in the jquery.validate.js code? I'm assuming the former.

Comment: @AdamLevitt, YES, your initial assumption is correct.  No need to modify the Validate plugin.  It's meant to be implemented within `.validate()` initialization, just like in [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfKk7/).

Comment: Thanks @Sparky ... your third solution solved my "onfocusout" problem that doesn't work the first time just like u said.

`onfocusout: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 5):

@Sparky is right, The correct answer is to remove the `onkeyup` option, my fiddle was working because I removed the `onkeyup` option not because I changed it to `keyup`.

By default the validation will happen on keyup event, if you want to turn off this feature then you have to add the setting `onkeyup: false`.

See the updated demo.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p7Vg9/3/)

Comment: This answer definitely looks good, yet for some reason it's not working for me.

Comment: This answer doesn't work because there are no such options for this plugin.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: @Sparky thanks, I think it is the second time you are correcting me on this. I'll try not to forget it again

Comment: @AdamLevitt which version of validator is used? are you getting the same error or different one

Answer (score 3):

boolean values are not valid values for onkeyup event. Instead add a function, on what is needed to be done.
Try something like:

```
    onkeyup: function(element) {
           $(element).valid(); 
    }
    onblur: function(element) { 
         $(element).valid(); 
    }
```

Comment: True. However, if the OP wants validation to occur on every keyup event, he simply needs to remove the `onkeyup` option in order to restore the "onkeyup" functionality already built into the plugin.    It's also not as simple as `$(element).valid()`.

Comment: Additionally, you are only **half** correct by stating _"boolean values are not valid values for onkeyup event"_.  As per documentation, a boolean `false` is the valid way to disable this option.  Only a boolean `true` is not valid.

Comment: Finally, `onblur` is not a valid option for this plugin.  It's called `onfocusout`.

Comment: Thank you. after some hours, search and ... see your answer and worked.

Answer (score 3):

How about extending onkeyup:

```
    $('#signup-form').validate({

        onkeyup: function(element) {
            var element_id = $(element).attr('id');
            if (this.settings.rules[element_id].onkeyup !== false) {
                $(element).valid();
            }
        },
```

So now within rules you can do this:

```
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 25,
                onkeyup: false, /* on blur validation */
            },
            password: {
                required: true,                   
                passwordmeter: true,
                onkeyup: true, /* on keyup validation */
            },
```

By extending **onkeyup** we made it a default behaviour, so sticking `onkeyup: true` is optional.

Comment: **Does not work and causes a bunch of JavaScript errors**: https://jsfiddle.net/L7vza07w - Also, plugin options are intended to be global for the entire form, they are never assigned on a field-by-field basis within the rules object.

Comment: BTW - within the `.validate()` method, it should be `this.element(element)`, never `$(element).valid()`. In certain situations, the latter can cause an infinite loop

Comment: docs for this.element(): https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

Comment: Why can `onkeyup` be written in `rules` ? In Document, `onkeyup` is only allowed to be in options of `validate()`

Comment: see: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-onkeyup-for-single-field