# Why does jQuery validate returning 1 for true on a non-async remote request, and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery.validate library to check if a form field matches an array of data.

[Here's the documentation for the remote method.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options)

When it returns true, jQuery.validate displays a `1` in an error field, and blocks the form as if there's been an error. I get the same result even if I have nothing but `echo true;` in my PHP file. Every reference I can find to this suggests setting `async:false`, which I've done. The code below is accurate to my web page:

```
var unl_validator = jQuery('.unlimited_coupon_form').validate({
    rules: {
        coupon: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            remote: {
                url: "<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/inc/checkCoupon.php",
                async:false,
                data: {
                    coupon: function(){
                        return jQuery('#subscribe_coupon').val();
                    },
                },
                type: "post",

            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        coupon: { required: "Please enter a valid coupon.", minlength: "Please enter a valid coupon.", remote: "This coupon code is not valid." }
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    onblur: true
});
```

Comment: You have another problem in your code.  `onblur: true` is not a valid option and should be removed entirely.  It's called `onfocusout` and this is already the default behavior.  You really only have three options:  1.  leave out `onfocusout` and it remains functional as a default, 2.  set `onfocusout` to `false` to disable it, or 3.  Specify a custom function to over-ride the default `onfocusout` function.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104059/594235 ~ It's about the `onkeyup` option, but the same idea applies to the `onfocusout` option.

Comment: Thank you for the catch and general information Sparky, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the validation plugin know what to do with true being displayed? Doesn't sound like it. You probably need to display something else in PHP.

To properly output a server response, a simple string is not enough. In PHP you can use JSON as such:

```
$result = true;
echo json_encode($result);
```

or if you need to output specific values

```
$result = new stdClass();
$result->someField = true;
$result->otherField = false;
echo json_encode($result);
// the above will output {someField: 1, otherField: 0};
```

Comment: It says it wants `true` back: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Comment: Apologies for downvoting, you were correct. I needed to output the `true` like so: `$output = json_encode(true); echo $output;`