# jQuery Validate plugin - how to auto validate as you type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in order to verify form on client side.

One of my requirements is that form must be validated as client type in input or textarea fields.
[jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) has an option `onkeyup`, but it's same as without it.

For testing purposes, I created **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yjgQG/)**.

What can be done?

Comment: explain behavior wanted in more detail. It doesn't seem very user friendly to display errors for each keystroke if that's what is wanted

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. For me that very cool feature lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We generally use the `keyup` event for this purpose. So you should simply add a function to be executed when the keyup event is fired, like this:

```
onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
    $(element).valid();
}
```

If you look at the code of the plugin, you'll see that the `keyup` method will pass the `element` (the input element or textarea) and the `event` object every time the keyup event is fired: you can use them to customize the behavior. The `valid()` method simply checks if the selected element is valid and shows the appropriate message.

See your jsfiddle example updated: http://jsfiddle.net/yjgQG/2/

Comment: Well this certainly work, and therefore I'll mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Validating "on key up" is the default operation of the plugin.  You should not need to specify the `onkeyup` option in this case.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/yyR9C/

Comment: Looks like Sparky is using an older version (1.10) while RhymeGuy the latest (1.11.1). Probably they behave differently. The demos on his page do not validate on keyup: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ (or maybe a bug?)

Comment: My mistake... _immediate_ `onkeyup` validation was a bug in version 1.10.  In the latest version (1.11.1), you have to submit the form or leave focus before you'll get any `onkeyup` behavior on a field.  Please edit your answer so it unlocks the voting... then I'll remove my down-vote.

Comment: Yes, a bug in version 1.10 - https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/541

Comment: +1, reversed my vote.  I should have read my own previous answer about proper behavior:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104059/594235