# jquery validation plugin does not validate when input comes with values from server

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ficukiriyi/1/edit)

the problem:

`<input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required value="test">`

comes with given value `test`. Now when removing the value, the validation plugin does not get triggered.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Name comes with value, when value removed, no error shows!</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required value="test">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" value="" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>

    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $("#commentForm").validate();  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation, by default, validation is "Lazy".

> [Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo)

This means that simply loading a form and deleting a value will do nothing.  You would have to wipe out the value and click the submit button to trigger validation.  Then all subsequent interactions are validated on the `keyup` and `focusout` events.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yo4y9s64/**

---

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104059/594235) to implement "Eager" validation...

```
onkeyup: function (element, event) {
    if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
        return;
    } else {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/yo4y9s64/1/**

Comment: hm ok. But you know, that doesn't make sense. He gets a valid form, makes it invalid manually by pressing buttons on the keyboard, but gets no feedback. So I have to write a listener for keyup myself that triggers a valid on the form ? that's silly

Comment: @Toskan, I did not say that.  I simply explained how it works by default and quoted the documentation to that effect.  If you want "Eager" validation, it's a simple modification that's been answered before:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104059/594235