# jQuery validation, disabling onkeyup for an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation, I want to disable keyup validation for a certain element so I'm using the code below : -

```
$("form").validate({
    onkeyup: function (element) {
        if (element.id == 'tx_username') {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This just disables it for everything and not just the desired element. Does anyone know how I can disable the keyup validation for just the element specified. 'tx_username' in this case

Comment: Your `if` conditional needs an `else` that puts back the default `onkeyup` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like below.

```
     onkeyup: function (element, event) {

     if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
           return;
     } else {
     if (element.id != 'tx_username') {
           this.element(element);
     }
```

Referred link - [jQuery.validate.js onkeyup = true error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103289/jquery-validate-js-onkeyup-true-error)

Comment: FYI @Shazoo - The code from that [old thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103289/jquery-validate-js-onkeyup-true-error) came from version 1.11.1 of the plugin.  It's now up to version 1.15.   See [my answer on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36413930/594235) for the updated version.  Notice how the `shift`, `ctrl`, `alt`, etc. keys are ignored by the latest `onkeyup` function.

Answer (score 2):

> This just disables it for everything and not just the desired element.

When you use the `onkeyup` option, your custom function is going to completely over-ride the plugin's default function.  Since you have no `else` statement, then nothing else will happen when the field is not a match for `tx_username`... effectively disabling `onkeyup` validation entirely.

```
onkeyup: function (element) {
    if (element.id == 'tx_username') {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The solution is to incorporate [the default `onkeyup` code](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js) into yours...

```
onkeyup: function (element, event) {
    var excludedKeys = [
        16, 17, 18, 20, 35, 36, 37,
        38, 39, 40, 45, 144, 225
    ];
    if (element.id == 'tx_username') { // disable 'onkeyup' for this field
        return false;  
    } else { // otherwise, use the default code
        if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" || $.inArray(event.keyCode, excludedKeys) !== -1) {
            return;
        } else if (element.name in this.submitted || element.name in this.invalid) {
            this.element(element);
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ff77xbvb/**

---

**NOTE**:  This later version of the `onkeyup` function will ignore the following keys...

```
// Shift       => 16
// Ctrl        => 17
// Alt         => 18
// Caps lock   => 20
// End         => 35
// Home        => 36
// Left arrow  => 37
// Up arrow    => 38
// Right arrow => 39
// Down arrow  => 40
// Insert      => 45
// Num lock    => 144
// AltGr key   => 225
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery's `.off()` [method](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

`$("#tx_username", form).off("keyup");`

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bowebukawi/2/edit?html,js,console,output)