# jQuery Validate custom rule for comparing two properties not equal by ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to compare two input text fields of a form using a custom rule for jQuery Validate.

I tried the following code

```
//Our validation script will go here.

$(document).ready(function(){
     //custom validation rule - text only
     $.validator.addMethod("NotEqualTo", 
             function(value, element) {
                 return ???;
             }, "Two Properties are matching"
    );

    $("#frmUpdatePassword").validate({
        onfocusout: true,
        rules: {
            NewPassword: {
                NotEqualTo: '#OldPassword'                }
        },
        messages: {
            NewPassword: {
                NotEqualTo: "Two Properties are having same values"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML `TextBox` is

```
<input type="password" id="OldPassword" name="OldPassword" />
<input type="password" id="NewPassword" name="NewPassword" />
```

Kindly assist me how to compare for not equal of two properties in a generic manner not only for comparing these two fields.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Here I will pass the property ID instead of value...

Answer (score 1):

The Custom Validation Rule should be

```
$.validator.addMethod('NotEqualTo', function (value, element, param) {

       var str1 = value  || '';
       var str2 = $(param).val() || '';

       return $.trim(str1) != $.trim(str2);

}, 'Invalid: Two values are matching');
```

The Rule should be

```
rules: {
    NewPassword: {
        NotEqualTo: '#OldPassword'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: settings[eventType].call is not a function`

Comment: @Mastero, you should never set `onfocusout: true`.  Read the docs, "`true` is not a valid value" and could break the built-in functionality.  If you want `onfocusout` enabled, simply leave this option out and that's already the default.  This is the source of your error.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, I had face same issue and resolve by below mentionion code.

```
//Our validation script will go here.
$(document).ready(function(){
     //custom validation rule - text only
     $.validator.addMethod("NotEqualTo", function(value, element) {

        var OldPassword = $("#OldPassword").val() || null;

        if(value == OldPassword)
        {
            return true; //Error fire!
        }
        else
        {
            return false; //Error Not fire!
        }
     }, "Two Properties are matching");

    $("#frmUpdatePassword").validate({
        onfocusout: true,
        rules: {
            NewPassword: {
                NotEqualTo: true;
            }
        },
        messages: {
            NewPassword: {
                NotEqualTo: "Two Properties are having same values"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Your over all code is fine! just update validation method.

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: settings[eventType].call is not a function`

Comment: Okay..., It's related to JQuery version issue, Please refer link: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/428, and update the `onfocusout` param from the validation plugin setup. also try to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103289/jquery-validate-js-onkeyup-true-error

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  Use `return false` to trigger a validation error, not `true`.